# Pass variables in url to get specific JSON output

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm attempting to create an api, I'm currently trying to append variables to the url to get specific data back in the JSON output.. I can currently display all contents of a table.   Any advice would be appreciated.. Please see code below...

```
$connection = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);

if( ! $connection ) die( "Error ".mysqli_connect_error() );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$array_post = array();


while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array_post[] = $data;

}

echo json_encode($array_post);
```

Comment: any problem with the code? or asking for advice only?

Comment: what specific data you want to append to the URL?

Comment: Add a counter to your array post while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array_post[$counter] = $data;
   $counter ++;
}

Comment: @milankyada  Code works fine and returns the contents of the table in JSON format...  Just advice on how to return specific data as JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean an api response after a POST or GET Request? Am I right?

If it is, then you can do this...

```
    $response = $array_post;
    http_response_code(200);
    print json_encode($response);
```

You need a stream to output the JSON data, you can set the HTTP status code by http_response_code($code) function and then print the response.

There are packages out there that could handle api request and response.
I suggest you take a look about Curl or much better the GuzzleHttp.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can store particular values return from SQL query to array keys like this

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $array_post['key2'][] = $data['key2'];
    $array_post['key2'][] = $data['key2'];

}

echo json_encode($array_post);
```

Use only those values which you required to pass in URL.
If you need all the records then your code is right.
If you are thinking about some records then change your query to
like `SELECT field1,field2 FROM table_name`.
because some times it will affect performance of executing SQL query.

Comment: Oddly this only returns the 7th row from the table. This is confusing and very strange

Comment: Sorry for that.
I just edited my answer. Added `[]` after `$array_post['key2']`

Comment: Thanks!    So how would i be able to return specific results in JSON? Would something like this work?          "http://localhost/api/api.php?post_title=Strawbrerry&post_description=Strawberry"

Comment: you have to remove `double quote` at the end of the URL if it is not necessary otherwise use `htmlspecialchars()`.